# Hyphen List in HTML page is not working in IE 8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The below code is not working in IE 8, other than this browser it's working in all browsers. Can anyone help me how to fix this?

**CSS**

```
ul.hyphen-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-left: 1.5em;
    padding-left: 1em;
    text-indent: -0.85em;
}

ul.hyphen-list li:before {
    content: "- ";
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="hyphen-list">
    <li>This is line 1<br/>part 2</li>
    <li>This is line 2</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ul.hyphen-list {
  list-style: none;
}
```

tested on browser stack in IE8; works just fine - http://jsfiddle.net/9RGeB/7/

http://jsfiddle.net/9RGeB/7/show/

Remember: IE 7 does not support :before

http://css-tricks.com/browser-support-pseudo-elements/